# JSON File not saving to Heroku Worker

Tags: python, json, heroku

JSON Files aren't saving in my Heroku worker, Is there a way to fix this? I need to cache a JSON file so I can compare against the live version from a website. I'm using Python. Everything works just fine on my Local machine but when hosted on Heroku whenever it runs a check if there is differences it just sends old data that was already detected as a difference.

Comment: are you running only one worker? (each dyno has it's own filesystem)

is there a deploy in between? Heroku restarts dynos and doesn't keep the data at least every 24 hours, and at every deploy. 

https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: Just running One worker, the files upload just fine but in the script I have it so the files update whenever it detects a change, but the file does not update so when I get the notifications sent of new changes it slowly grows with all the products that are new since I did a last push to my github.